# Clang Format Rule for Nested Struct Fields

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang-format

Which [clang format style option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) controls how clang formats nested struct fields?  If there isn't one, are there any known work arounds to the following?

Consider the following fake program

```
void main()
{
    /* ... */
    struct_type thing = {
        .foo = foo,
        .params =
            {
                .start = {.stamp = 1, .when = 1},
                .url = "https://httpbin.org/",
            },
    };
}
```

We have some older build environments with clang-format 3.8 installed.  When we run clang-format on the above program, the nested struct fields end up on the same line

```
$ clang-format sample.c 

/* ... */
      .params =
          {
              .start = {.stamp = 1, .when = 1}, .url = "https://httpbin.org/",
          },
/* ... */
```

However, when using clang-format 6.0.0, those nested fields end up on different lines.

```
$ clang-format sample.c 

/* ... */

      .params =
          {
              .start = {.stamp = 1, .when = 1},
              .url = "https://httpbin.org/",
          },
/* ... */

}
```

Does anyone here know which (if any) clang-format style rules control this and which version(s) those rules are available in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, clang-format will place struct fields on different lines, as in the original code and as in the output of clang-format-6.0.

I wasn't able to find an option to control this, explicitly.

However, clang-format-3.8 forcing the fields on the same line seems to be a bug.
There's a field called `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators`, that controls the wrapping of binary operators (see [clang-format 3.8 documentation](http://releases.llvm.org/3.8.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)). That field defaults to `None`, which tells clang-format not to break before binary operators. The thing is, clang-format wrongly recognizes this structure, which has exactly two fields, as a binary operator...

Therefore, to work around the issue with clang-format 3.8, set `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators` to `All`. This will have the side effect of changing the way binary operators wrap, but hopefully that would be acceptable (since it's probably uncommon to have a binary expression that exceeds the column limit).

Hope this helps.
BTW, I found this by comparing the `--dump-config` outputs of 3.8 and 3.8 with `-style=webkit`, once I realized that webkit style doesn't have that wrong behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @valiano!  Setting `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators` seems to have fixed this, and extra thanks for mentioning the `--dump-config` option, which I'm sure will be useful for the future silly pedantic style bug hunts I sign myself up for.

Comment: @AlanStorm Sure, glad to have helped!